# How can I synchronise usernames between Chiselapp and local Fossil?

Tags: fossil

My username on [Chiselapp](http://chiselapp.com) differs from my username on my local machine (which seems to be my Fossil username). I have noticed that both appear in my commit history. How can I synchronise these usernames so that I am the same user in both locations?

My hunch is that it will be easiest to define a new Fossil username locally. Does the "user ID" value matter? Can I shun the old username? Ideally I would want to do this per-local-repo, not globally on my local machine, in case I use a different Fossil service provider at a later date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this in a much faster and consistent way using `fossil configuration`. The [configuration command](https://www.fossil-scm.org/xfer/help/config) covers a number of "areas", including your ticket configuration, UI css etc.

For what you describe, you would want to push or pull the `user` area:

```
fossil configuration pull user
```

Assuming that you have a remote-url in place. You can also push your user data if you so wish. The method you describe through the UI also works, of course. Working with `configuration` is faster and has more options.

You can change the username in a check-in. Through the UI, for example on the timeline, click on a checkin and then select "Edit" on the bottom of "Overview" (just above "tags and properties"). You will find that the first item you can edit is "User". Of course a record of the change will be made as whatever user you are logged in when you make the change. It will say something like:

```
Control file referencing [6ca0f57251] - 
Edit [58b7da6d030f457a87c67aebbdfd2dfcab674d28|58b7da6d03]: 
Change user to ""changedUser"". by currentuser on 2015-02-12 22:04:07.
```

I mention that last part to note that you still cannot change the history, as any change will be recorded as such. As far as I know there is no way to do this for every single occurrence of a particular user name through the configuration settings.

Comment: I wish this was the default behaivour of fossil... instead of each clone having it's own permission set. I know this is more in line with the "Distributed Nature of Fossil" but it has bitten me several times.

Answer (score 1):

To change your username locally:

- Run `fossil ui` to open the web interface
- Select "Admin", "Users" and your username
- On the User page, change your username
- Confirm that the password field is clear
- Click "Apply changes"
- Close the web interface
- Run `fossil user list` to confirm that only the new username appears
- Future local commits will be made with this username

The old (unsynchronised) username will still appear in the commit history. It appears these records cannot be changed.